# Firebase requires to add 2 ips but godaddy allows just 1 'a' type in dns

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to connect firebase to godaddy. the problem is they gave me 2 ips to be added to the records as type 'A'. But i spoke to the godaddy support and they said it's not possible. Just one. Kinda nonsense...

[image]

They added just one of them and as expected, error in firebase.

Comment: Hmmm.... this developer seems to have had no problem adding multiple A records on godaddy: https://medium.com/@archana_june/firebase-custom-domain-setup-with-godaddy-8b7acf66ccec (step 14 and 15). On the other hand, the developer in this video seems to being CNAME records instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFyKmzVLHjs

Comment: Hey Frank. thanks for the response. But not my case. as i said godaddy said said me  - only one ip